# Calculating the rank of a matrix whose entries include variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to calculate the rank of the matrix
$$A(x) :=
\begin{pmatrix}
x& 1& -1& 1\\
1& x& 1& -1\\
-1& 1& x& 1\\
1& -1& 1& x
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Since I did not want to calculate a echelon form that involves a variable, I first calculated the determinant of $A(x)$, which is $(x+1)^3(x-3)$, by using Laplace expansion.  Then I plugged in the roots of the polynomial and calculated the ranks.  The result is that the rank of $A(x)$ is 1 if $x=-1$, 3 if $x=3$ and 4 otherwise.

My question is how to do this alternatively.  Since the entries of $A(x)$ follow a regular pattern, I believe that there is a better way to calculate the rank. I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure the rank is 2 when $x = -1$?

Comment: @Amzoti actually, it is 1. I'll fix the question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix  might be what you were thinking, regards to the regular pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you expect by "alternatively". A faster (but less trivial) way to compute the ranks would be the following : 
Your quantity $\det(A(-x))$ is the characteristic polynomial of A(0)
$$\det(A(-x))=(x-1)^3(x+3)$$

A(0) being symmetric, it is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis, and then the minimum polynomial is $(x-1)(x+3)$.

For a diagonalizable matrix where the characteristic polynomial is $\prod (x-a_i)^{m_i}$, 
you can show that (non trivial (Edit : No, this is trivial on diagonal form)) $\dim \ker(A-a_i \mathrm{Id})=m_i$.

Then you immediatly get your result for the ranks